# Rxjs timer restarts after unsubscribe

Tags: angular, timer, rxjs, unsubscribe

I started making a simple game to test reflexes. When the red rectangle turns green, the player must click on the figure and the result is displayed. The problem is that after clicking on the rectangle the timer starts again.I use unsubscribe for this, but no results.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w8uejd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Code:

HTML

```
<div (click)="onRegtangleClicked()" class="rectangle" id="rectangle"></div>
<div class="button">
    <button (click)="onStartClicked()" class="btn btn-success">Start</button>
</div>
<p class="text">You score is:  {{time}} (lower is better)</p>
```

SCSS

```
.rectangle {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
.button{
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    position: relative;
}
.text{
    font-size: large;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 40%;
}
```

typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reflexgame',
  templateUrl: './reflexgame.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reflexgame.component.scss'],
})
export class ReflexgameComponent implements OnInit {
  time: number = 0;
  subscription: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onStartClicked() {
    let randomNumber:number = Math.random() * 5;
    setInterval(() => {
      document.getElementById('rectangle')!.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      this.observableTimer();
    }, randomNumber * 1000);
  }
  onRegtangleClicked() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
  observableTimer() {
    this.subscription = timer(0, 1).subscribe((val) => {
      this.time = val;
    });
  }
}
```

I don't know where I'm wrong?

Comment: So do you want to stop after clicking rectangle ?

Comment: Yes and then the result to be displayed on the screen

Comment: Can you try this? `this.subscription.complete();` inside your `onRegtangleClicked()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timer is restarting again and again because in the method `onStartClicked()` you are using `setInterval`. The logic you define inside an interval is executed continuously every *x* seconds until you call the `clearInterval(theIntervalToClear)`.

In your case, you should use a `setTimeout` to only trigger the logic once after *x* seconds pass.

cheers

Comment: Yep ! I am stupid. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your code break is because

1. You are calling `unsubscribe()` even before you creating a subscription: to fix that you can add a flag so to know whether the subscription is active or not.
2. When you create an interval it is better to clear the interval.

Got it working for me with both the logic, give it a try